# Strange behavior of Iterable in AVRO (inside a MapReduce)

Tags: mapreduce, iterable, avro

I saw a quiete strange behavior when using Avro in a MapReduce Job. Indeed the Iterable used 
is very strange : iterator.next do not point on an object but on something which change its value at each call of the function "next" !!

Example :

```
public static class MyAvroReducer extends AvroReducer<Long, MyAvroType,
Pair<Long, MyAvroType>> {


    @Override
    public void reduce(Long user, Iterable<MyAvroType> listAvroType,
            AvroCollector<Pair<Long,MyAvroType>> collector,
            Reporter reporter)
    throws IOException {
        // basically here I am expecting a list of two MyAvroType object
        // The first one who has a field "type" equals to "foo" and the second
        // who has a filed "type" equals to "bar"

        MyAvroType foo;
        MyAvroType bar;

        for (MyAvroType obj : listAvroType){
           if (obj.getType().equals("foo") {foo = obj;}
           else if (obj.getType().equals("bar") {bar = obj;}

        }
        system.out.println("FOO: " + foo.getType());
        system.out.println("FOO: " + bar.getType());

}
```

The standard output says :

FOO: bar

BAR: bar

How has been coded the Iterable here ? and why ?? Or maybe I do something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I found your question because I had the same problem.  Tests I ran seem to show that there is only one instance being returned by the Iterable for all iterations.  The Iterable must be replacing the content of the same object each time it reads a new AVRO object.  I ended up with a list of thousands of the last object returned.  I found that, as soon as I called iterator.next(), the object I had from the previous iteration would suddenly morph into the new object.

I can sort of understand why they do it this way, as an Iterable is used to enable a limitless number of objects through processing - i.e., more than could possibly fit in memory at one time.  So, they are not expecting anyone to hold onto an object after the call to iterator.next().

If you need to refer to any previous objects returned from the iterable, you'll have to copy the object into a new instance before going to the next object in the Iterable.

I used Cloner from google's cloning-1.8.5 tool to solve the problem.  My objects are about five or six levels deep of nesting, but it seemed to work.

[Google cloning-1.8.5](http://code.google.com/p/cloning/)

Another alternative would be to implement your own copy method on every object.

Thanks,
Vick

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used cloning too to solve the probleme. By the way I can understand the optimization but it is not what a developer expect about a iterator behavior...